# In Obj-c (xCode) how do I display this string to the text field?

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring

I am trying to make a practice application that takes two entered words (word1, word2) and puts them together to make a compound word. I am very new to this and would like to know the correct way to display these two variables under the action "buttonPressed."

Here's the header file...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Word_CombinerViewController : UIViewController {
    UITextField *word1;
    UITextField *word2;
    UITextField *display;
    UIButton *mashButton;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *word1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *word2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *display;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *mashButton;
-(IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;


@end
```

And here's the implementation file (.m)...

```
#import "Word_CombinerViewController.h"

@implementation Word_CombinerViewController
@synthesize word1;
@synthesize word2;
@synthesize display;
@synthesize mashButton;


-(IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}

-(IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender {
    [word1 resignFirstResponder];
    [word2 resignFirstResponder];
}

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *newText = [NSString: @word1, @word2]
    display.text = newText;
    [newText release]

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [word1 release];
    [word2 release];
    [display release];
    [mashButton release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I know this code is probably full of errors, but everyone has gotta start somewhere, right?
Any feedback would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Do yourself a favor and learn Obj-C before getting into iPhone development. In other words, don't make the mistake I made three years ago.

Comment: OK, that took all the red flags away. However when I run the app and I click the button it crashes... any ideas why? The code seems sound in xcode.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *newText = [NSString: @word1, @word2]
```

This code doesn't make any sense. The first part of a message is the receiver, and it won't have any colons in it. The second part is the message itself, i.e. the method name along with any necessary parameters. What you're looking for is:

```
NSString *newText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", word1, word2];
```

The -stringWithFormat: method uses a format string (very much like printf()) and a variable number of parameters to fill in the placeholders in the format string.

Also, when you create a string (or any object) using a "convenience method" like this, you shouldn't release it. You didn't retain or alloc or copy it, so it's not your responsibility to release it. You'll want to remove that line from your -buttonPressed method.

Comment: You're absolutely right; post edited to fix that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *newText = [word1.text stringByAppendingString:word2.text]
    display.text = newText;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to remove that -release.